# Rearranging an differential equation equal to zero

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I am analyzing some exercise solutions, however, I am not sure if they are right because using my logic I got a different sign.

Given the differential equation:

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{dY}{dt}=k_{sy}X-k_{2}E_{T}\dfrac{Y}{K_{m}+Y} = 0
\end{align*}

Extracting X from the equation the exercise solution says:

\begin{align*}
X=\dfrac{k_{2}E_{T}}{k_{sy}}\dfrac{Y}{K_{m}+Y}
\end{align*}

I did the following steps:

\begin{align*}
-k_{sy}X=-k_{2}E_{T}\dfrac{Y}{K_{m}+Y}
\end{align*}

In my reasoning as \begin{align*} k_{sy}X \end{align*} was negative in the left side of the equation it would go back to the right side as positive \begin{align*} k_{sy} \end{align*}  dividing the \begin{align*} -k_{2}E_{T}\end{align*} and  then be:

\begin{align*}
X=-\dfrac{k_{2}E_{T}}{k_{sy}}\dfrac{Y}{K_{m}+Y}
\end{align*}

As a negative number divided by a positive number is negative. It should be just a basic math concept that I am missing but I would be grateful for any enlightenment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In algebra we depart from the concept that if $$A=B$$ then $$f(A)=f(B)$$
I think you may be confused about the change of signs because terms change signs when they change sides of the equation, but notice that what you do when changing a term from one side of the equality to the other is subtract/add it to both sides, therefore, on one side it cancels out and on the other it appears but with signs changed.

When trying to get rid of a factor, this is not the case, because division does not change the signs of terms. In your case, you should be dividing both sides by $-k_{ys}$, see what you get.